# Expression Language/ Comparing two parameters (JSP)

Tags: jstl, expression

I have a pretty simple question. If I'm comparing two parameters in a JSP page using c:if, which is correct?

```
<c:if test="${order.id}==${item.id}">
```

or

```
<c:if test="${order.id==item.id}">
```

?

Comment: IMO, it's cleaner to use eq instead of ==.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second one. ${} denotes EL expression, inside which you perform comparison.